# Деление длинного числа на два

Tags: c++, деление

Программа должна разделить длинное число на два, но считает не правильно, помогите найти ошибку. Исходное число должно остаться без изменений, поэтому все действия проделываются над делителем.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void Parser(string, int *); //переводит строку в число
void RezhuDelitel(int, string &, int *); //делит число на два

int main()
{
    string number;
    cin >> number;

    int *parseNumber = new int[number.size() - 1];
    Parser(number, parseNumber);

    int colDelitel = 2;

    int *rezhDel = new int[number.size() - 1]; //массив цифр делителя
    string delitel = number;

    Parser(delitel, rezhDel);

    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(rezhDel); i++)cout << rezhDel[i];
    cout << endl;

    cout << sizeof(rezhDel);
    RezhuDelitel(colDelitel, delitel,rezhDel); //уменьшит делитель в два раза

    return 0;
}


void Parser(string number, int *parseNumber) //переводит строку в массив
{
    for (int i = 0; i < number.size(); i++)
    {
        parseNumber[i] = number[i] - '0';
    }
}

void RezhuDelitel(int colDelitel, string &delitel, int *rezhDel)
{
    int ost = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= delitel.size() - 1; i++)
    {
        int cur = ost * 10 + rezhDel[i];
        rezhDel[i] = cur / colDelitel;
        ost = cur%colDelitel;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i++)
    {
        cout << rezhDel[i];
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: А в чем именно вопрос то?

Comment: @darkwoolf, исправил, спасибо, торопился , пока набирал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю, в чем ваша проблема (вы забыли ее изложить...), но для начала - `sizeof(rezhDel);` равен 4 в типичной 32-разрядной системе, и 8 в типичной 64-разрядной, а вовсе не количеству элементов в выделенном массиве.

Comment: @Haryy, sizeof() не определяет размерность массива?

Comment: Конечно, нет. Это размер типа переменной. Т.е. в данном случае - сколько байт занимает в памяти указатель.

Comment: @Haryy, а как узнать тогда размер массива? Погуглил. написано, что нужно  sizeof(rezhDel)/sizeof(rezhDel[0], это будет верно в моем случае?

Comment: Нет, это для объявленного массива, ну, типа `int arr[] = {1,2,3,4}`. В вашем случае - просто запоминайте его размер в отдельной переменной. Или используйте стандартный класс `vector` или `array`.

Comment: @Haryy, спасибо, помогло. Без вас бы никогда не додумался, что дело в sizeof()